# Unitary connection and Hermitian connection

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I am confused with the two notions.

I basically understand Hermitian connection: it is a complex analog of metric-compatible connection on $TM$, a connection that preserves the hermitian metric $h$ defined for a general complex vector bundle.

But what about unitary connection? I searched for a while but did not find a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, unitary connection refers to a compatible connection on the principal $U(n)$-bundle $P\to M$ (for some $n$). If you associate with $P$ a hermitian vector bundle $E\to M$ in the standard fashion, then unitary connection on $P$ will yield a hermitian connection on $M$ and vice versa. All this should be in Kobayashi and Nomizu "Foundations of Differential Geometry".

Edit: In the context of connections on vector bundles, "unitary connection" is  synonymous to "hermitian connection". Compare for instance [here](http://matematicas.uniandes.edu.co/~florent/resources/papers/Proc_VillaDeLeyva.pdf).

Comment: I thought this would be the case, until I came across a few statements like "Let $A$ be unitary connection on line bundle $L$".

Comment: One interpretation of this would be a connection admitting a compatible hermitian structure.

Comment: Thank you! This terminology is truly a bit confusing. I encounter a few times where "unitary connection" and "hermitian connection" on some vector bundles appear in one single sentence.